# SQLState 23000 - Integrity constraint violation 1062 Duplicate Entry

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, postman

I am using a custom made API Request to my database to generate a new entry.

My table structure looks like this:

**Table Structure**

```
    Schema::create('incidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('incident_id')->unique();
        $table->integer('incident_type')->unsigned();
        $table->string('location');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->double('latitude', 10, 6);
        $table->double('longitude', 10, 6);
        $table->date('date');
        $table->time('time');
        $table->smallInteger('incident_archived')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I set the Incident_Type to Unique as this is a requirement for my system. When I post a new entry to the system:

```
SERVER_IP/v1/incidents?incident_id=1&city=Muenchen&street=Fichtenstr.20&latitude=100&longitude=300
```

The first time works fine.

The second time:

```
SERVER_IP/v1/incidents?incident_id=2&city=Muenchen&street=Fichtenstr.20&latitude=100&longitude=300
```

when I use different incident_id I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'incidents_incident_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `incidents` (`street`, `city`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Fichtenstr.20, Muenchen, 100, 300, 2015-10-17 12:28:11, 2015-10-17 12:28:11))
```

Why is sending the request using the exact same entry even if I changed the data? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are not passing any value for incident_id so it defaults to an empty string each time.

```
insert into `incidents` (`street`, `city`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Fichtenstr.20, Muenchen, 100, 300, 2015-10-17 12:28:11, 2015-10-17 12:28:11))
```

Not a Laravel user so I can not tell you why it is not using the incident_id you pass in.